How do I persuade an inactive Facebook group administrator to hand over control?
Facebook Groups have Administrators given rights by Facebook to establish the Group, write a description, and set rules about who can join and who can post to the Group, as well as who can Moderate posts made to the Group (in addition to the Administrator themselves). What should be done when the Administrator is inactive and does not agree with changes requested by other memembers of the Group?
I read Facebook Group Admin FAQs. All the information assumes that actions are taken by (one or more) Administrators following requests made to them. The FAQs did not provide sufficient information. I do not want to take on the role of Administrator, but I know that there are other members of the Facebook Group that would prefer changes to be made. I am seeking comments from anyone else who have encountered similar problems.
I was expecting Facebook Group Admin FAQs to offer a wider range of alternatives.
